# How to "un-sort" a JTable?

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtable

I created a `TableRowSorter` for a `JTable`, and I was able to sort the table correctly. But is there a way to get the table back to its original state before I sorted it? I tried clicking on the table header, but it seems that it only sorts the table in ascending or descending order, and it doesn't return the table back to its original state prior to the sort. Is it possible to *un-sort* the table and get it back to its original state? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *only* way is to hang onto the original state and restore it when you fire an "unsort" event.

So you'll need to maintain the original row order, in a List or array, that you can restore.  You could also keep a reference to a duplicate of the original `DefaultTableModel`.

Comment: I would suggest using a Stack

Comment: Good idea - what would you put on it?  DefaultTableModel references?  That would allow multiple "undo" options.  Create a DTM, add it to the stack, display.  I like it...

Comment: sorry, but that's simply wrong - nulling the sortKeys is _the_ way to go for unsorting the table completely (and always have been ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Empty `sortKeys` list indicates the view should be unsorted. Try the following to restore original row order:

```
table.getRowSorter().setSortKeys(null);
```

Read more in [RowSorter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/RowSorter.html#setSortKeys%28java.util.List%29) spec.

Answer (score 1):

table.setRowSorter(new TableRowSorter<>(table.getModel()));

This should work if emptying the sort keys doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, after sorting and changing to an empty table, a **NullPointer** Exception was thrown from my model by **getColumClass**.
I solved this by disabling the auto sorter before emptying my table and enabling the sorter again.

```
this.mainTable.setAutoCreateRowSorter(false);
this.tableModel.removeAllElements();
this.mainTable.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
this.mainTable.repaint();
this.mainScrollPane.doLayout();
```